# Capturing Click Event to Pass Into Function in Angular App

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have set up some filters a user can click on in order to filter a list display in my Angular app. The relevant code in my view looks like this:

```
<md-checkbox *ngFor="let option of categoryFilters.options" [(ngModel)]="option.value" (click)="filterByCategory($event)">
     {{option.label}}
</md-checkbox>
```

You'll notice that I have a "filterByCategory()" function above. What I want to do with that is filter the list according to the value that the user clicks on from the md-checkbox list. So far I haven't been able to capture that value.

I've tried this in my component:

```
public filterByCategory(option) {
    console.log('Category filter ' + option + ' was clicked');
}
```

But that just prints the mouse event to the console:

> 'Category filter [object MouseEvent] was clicked'

I also tried using the two-way-bound value, like this:

```
public filterByCategory(option) {
    console.log('Category filter ' + this.option.value + ' was clicked');
}
```

But that returns 'undefined'.

By the way, the options I'm trying access the values of here look like this in my component:

```
private categoryFilters = {
    enabled: true,
    options: [
        { toolbarLabel: 'A', label: 'Option A', value: false },
        { toolbarLabel: 'B', label: 'Option B', value: false },
        { toolbarLabel: 'C ', label: 'Option C ', value: false }
    ],
    text: null
};
```

What can use to actually get the value that was clicked on, in order to pass that into the filter function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.
 `(click)="optionClicked(option)">`

```
optionClicked(option) {
console.log(option.value)
}
```

Comment: That gives me:
MdCheckboxChange {source: MdCheckbox, checked: true}

Comment: If I do: console.log(event.checked) -- I get "true". But what I need is the actual value.

Comment: I did not get you. What do you mean by the actual value?

Comment: So "true" means one of the three options was clicked. But I need to actually capture what the value was. So if option A is "Option A", I need to capture "Option A". So I  don't just need a boolean returned, I need the value of that clicked option.

Comment: This is still printing "false" to the console.

Comment: That is because i have consoled option.value. you can console option.

Comment: Cool. Got it to work with this: console.log(option.label);

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:**

You can also try this:

```html
<md-checkbox *ngFor="let option of categoryFilters.options" 
     [(ngModel)]="option.value" (change)="filterByCategory(option.label, $event)">
   {{option.label}}
</md-checkbox>

filterByCategory(value, checked) {
  if(checked) {
    console.log(value)
  }
}
```

---

**Original answer:**

You could do it like this: I removed the two-way-binding altogether, since we are using `$event` and `value`-attribute, so in this case `ngModel` is redundant. I also use `change`-event instead of `click`. So change your template to:

```html
<md-checkbox *ngFor="let option of categoryFilters.options" 
    value="{{option.label}}" (change)="filterByCategory($event)">
       {{option.label}}
</md-checkbox>
```

And in the component, let's see if the checkbox is checked before actually looking at the option value.

```ts
filterByCategory(event) {
  if(event.checked) {
    console.log(event.source.value)
  }
}
```

This seems to work fine:

### [Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/kJWUdgFS7DugHYstHRSe?p=preview)

Comment: I will try this. Thanks.

Comment: I am still getting 'undefined' in the console after trying this.

Comment: Updated answer with another option, would that work?

Comment: I will check now, thanks. By the way, I added info above as to how the options are modeled in the component.

Comment: With this I get "false" logged to the console upon one of the three options being clicked -- but no value returned.

Comment: You need to update the option.value to option.label, now that I saw your model, look updated answer :)

Comment: Looks like this will work! I now just need to make a tweak because now all 3 options are checked by default. I need them to be unchecked by default.

Comment: one last update to answer, also works: https://plnkr.co/edit/VHqefQOyI6WWq8okjd7S?p=preview

Comment: Thanks, both of the provided answers ultimately worked. Much appreciated.